# How can be proved that $L = \lbrace{ a^n b^m \mid n \le m \le 2n \lor m \le n \le 2m \rbrace}$ is not a regular language?

Tags: regular-language

> Prove the language is not regular: $L = \lbrace{ a^n b^m \mid n \le m \le 2n \lor m \le n \le 2m \rbrace}$.

I want to use the pumping lemma but I don't know which parts of the string to split up because it seems that the language's condition will always be met no matter how I split up the string. Is the language regular? If not, can I get a hint on how to split up the string?

Comment: I'm not sure this helps, but you can write $\{ (m,n) | (n \le m \le 2n) \lor (m \le n \le 2m) \} = \{(m,n) | m \le 2n \le 4m \} $.

Comment: That actually helps a lot but how did you come up with this? I'm not convinced both sides are equal

Comment: Ok nevermind I can see it now. But couldn't the left side also be {(m,n)|n≤2m≤4n}?

Comment: Yes. Draw a picture.

Comment: Right! So I don't think that would help me since {(m,n)|m≤2n≤4m} and {(m,n)|n≤2m≤4n} are true. Correct me if I'm wrong but in order for the language to be nonregular, both of those conditions have to be false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write $L= \{ a^n b^m | m \le 2n \le 4m \}$.

The pumping lemma says there exists some $p$ such that if
$|w| \ge p$, then we can write $w=xyz$ with $|y| \ge 1$, $|xy| \le p$ and
then $x y^k z \in L$ for all $k$.

Let $w \in L$ with $|w| \ge p$. Then we see that $y$ must have the form $y=a^l$ or $y=b^l$.

If $y=a^l$ (in which case $x,z$ have the form $z=a^r b^s$ and $x=a^t$) we can choose $k$ such that $lk > 2|z|$ in which case $m\le |z|$ and $n \ge lk > 2|z| \ge 2 m$ which
contradicts $w \in L$.

If $y=b^l$ (in which case $x,z$ have the form $x=a^r b^s$ and $z=b^t$) we can choose $k$ such that $lk > 2|x|$ in which case $n \le|x|$ and $m \ge lk > 2|x| \ge 2n$ which
contradicts $w \in L$.

Hence $L$ is not regular.